# Integration between Google Dialogflow and Salesforce?

Tags: salesforce, dialogflow-es, integration, progressive-web-apps

I created a Chatbot using Google Dialogflow to capture lead details and POST those in Salesforce CRM.
I'm stuck in creating an endpoint with the Salesforce Sandbox account. Are there any experts who can brief me on the flow in Salesforce?